# use dynamic css with change the langueage in nuxt3 and i18n

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nuxt-i18n

I am trying to add some new fonts according to change page and either if the web app comes with a specific language.
This is the code that I have added to my layouts/default page and it does not work properly.

```
if(head.value.htmlAttrs.dir=="rtl"){
  console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",head.value.htmlAttrs.dir)

  useHead({
  link: [{
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    type: 'text/css',
    // crossorigin: '',
    href: '/css/fa-font.css'
    },],
})}
```